# Need to ask for a user specified amount of Asteriks to be displayed on the screen in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm really bad at coding and I have a little bit of a start but I have no idea where to go from here.

```
if(choice == 4);
           System.out.println("how many asteriks do you want");
           number = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("*" + number);
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do? and what's the problem?

Comment: What you're doing right now is appending the number to the asterisk. Instead, you want to perform the print operation `x` times, so use a loop.

Comment: thanks for the help guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `while-loop` or `for-loop` in your code.

```
          while(number>=0){
            System.out.print("*");
            number--;
            }
```

Comment: thanks you very much :) that makes sense now that i'm looking at it.